# Abrir Modal com Delay e Depois de Fechado não Abrir Mais

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap-4

Estou tentando criar um modal bootstrap como tela de saudação de uma página. A parte dele abrir com delay eu consegui fazer sem problemas, mas preciso que quando o usuário fechar ele, ele não volte a ser exibido na próxima vez que o mesmo logar na tela. O código do modal é o padrão do bootstrap e vai conter apenas um texto simples.

```
$(window).on('load',function(){
    var delay = 1000;
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#notificacao').modal('show');
    },delay);
});
```

Comment: eai gnomo deu certo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/Window.localStorage) - nos permite armazenar dados de forma simples e sem expiração, ou seja, ficam lá enquanto não apagarmos por código ou pelo próprio navegador.

Sintaxe para salvar dados em localStorage: `localStorage.setItem("chave", "valor");`

Sintaxe para leitura de dados de localStorage: `var nomeVariavel = localStorage.getItem("chave");`

Sintaxe para remover dados de localStorage: `localStorage.removeItem("chave");`

```
$(window).on('load',function(){
    var isshow = localStorage.getItem('isshow');
    if (isshow== null) {
        localStorage.setItem('isshow', 1);

        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#notificacao').modal('show');
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

[image: Suporte ao navegador]

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(window).on('load',function(){
    var delay = 1000;
    setTimeout(function(){
          // puxa o item no localstorege
        let janela= localStorage.getItem('janela');
        //verifico se e igual a null
        if(janela == null){
        $('#notificacao').modal('show');
        // seto o item no local storege para que ele n seja mais null
        localStorage.setItem('janela', 'true');
        }
    },delay);
});
```